# lazy list in Fragment

Tags: android, list, lazy-loading, fragment

I am trying to implement a ListView with async image loading inside a Fragment.
For this purpose, I took [Fedor's LazyList](http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip) code.
The code works, however loaded images are not displayed until "scrolling them out" of the visible area and "scrolling in" again. That means the image is updated only if "getView()" is invoked again on the list item after the image was loaded.
I suspect the reason is that "activity.runOnUiThread()", which is invoked for loaded images, doesn't trigger a redraw of the Fragment inside the referenced Activity.
The Fragment class doesn't have such a method.
I tried to do "postInvalidate()" on the imageView, but that doesn't have any effect.
How to get this working?

Comment: May i know where you used Fragment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have made mistake in setTag() method inside the getView() method.

```
holder.imageView.setTag(loadURL);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(loadURL, activity, holder.imageView);
```

SetTag() and DisplayImage() both should have the same Image URL value.

Comment: you're right, I have overseen that line of code, thanks a lot!

Comment: @didi_X8 i had done the same mistake in past. Thats why at first look at your question, i caught it. I had passed around 2 days to catch this issue.

Comment: I see. Perfect example for how cooperation via Internet can boost productivity!

Comment: @didi_X8 you should read my words about stackoverflow as i feel the same: http://goo.gl/1Gmzw